# Complex image border, can this be made?

Tags: jquery, html, css

We designed a website in photoshop and now I'm trying to convert the design to a Wordpress template. This is all going well, except for one thing. I'm not sure how to create this kind of border for my images. Could this be done by using a css/jquery trick? We created a border over the image. I've attached an image as an example.

[image: This is the image]

The background around the image has different colors.

Comment: css can do many things, but it's not photoshop...

Comment: Is there any reason you can't have the border be part of the image file itself?

Comment: @Marc B Yes of course... I know. But that's not the question. My clients needs to upload his pictures in the CMS and the border needs to be attached to the images. Because my client doesn't have photoshop....

Comment: @taylorc93 that's the last scenario I'm thinking of. If there are no other flexible options

Comment: make the border transparent, and layer backgrounds? solid color -> fancy image -> normal content. that'd let the solid "meta-background" leak through the fancy image's transparent images, "coloring" them.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the CSS3 border-image property for this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

Here's the css you're probably looking for:

```
img {
  /* Set border to 10px, make it transparent
     in case border-image isn't supported */
  border: 10px solid transparent;

  /* Set the image and make it stretch around
     the image evenly */
  border-image: url(border.png) 50% stretch;
}
```

Edit: Another option would be to overlay the border over the image:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;
  height: 299px;
}
#container > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <img src="http://blog.protectedstatic.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/05/pointers.png" id="content" />
      <img src="http://www.clipartandgraphics.com/images/borders/bwwaves.gif" id="border" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the border to automatically apply overlay on the image you could make the border a .png and use divs to layer them. See this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/sqJtr/961/

Basically you have two divs, the main image and the overlay. The main image is what the client would upload to:

```
#main_image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000072921331/ecb6edfa73f25a3857df7991f1466962.jpeg");
}
```

The overlay image is the frame .png file you yourself add:

```
#overlay_image{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
    background-image: url("http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/windows/png32/256/000000/border-inner-256-000000.png");
}
```

This is just one option for how to get this done. Using this method the images do have to be a uniform size so this may not help you get the result you're looking for.